# Are there any results showing a prime exists in $(n^2/4-n,n^2/4)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I see interval proofs of a prime in $(2n,3n)$ and $(4n,5n)$ etc. all the time, and found one paper that showed it for up to $(519n,520n)$.

Are there results that show a prime in $(\frac{1}{4}n^2-n,\frac{1}{4}n^2)$ or anything similar? Or are the only proofs so far related in linear terms of $n$?

Comment: Whether there is always a prime between consecutive squares is a notorious open problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 3):

The precise thing you ask for is not known, but better than linear (and close to quadratic) is possible. The best thing we can prove at the moment is that for every large enough $x$, there is a prime in the interval $[x - x^{0.525}, x]$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results). The Riemann Hypothesis would improve the exponent $0.525$ to $0.5 + \epsilon$.

Comment: I'm missing something obvious about that result. I thought Legendre's conjecture was for a prime between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$, so e.g. 100 and 121, whereas this gives me $100+100^{0.525} \approx 111$. Where's my screwup?

Comment: For large enough $x$, $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ will be smaller than $x^2 + (x^2)^{0.525} = x^2 + x^{1.05}$. It's just that $x = 10$ in your example, and $10$ isn't large enough.

Answer (score 2):

[Oppermann's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) for $(n^2-n, n^2)$ is still open.